# Add comment content to the queston

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to `json_encode` data from the database but the file does not display more than 255 characters.

I have a table column with 812 characters and I want to return a json.

The column in which that data is saved is of type TEXT and it allows to save the 812 characters. But when I run `json_encode` from the table, it doesnot show anything and when I reduce the content, it returns the json and yet I need all the content.

This is what i get after i run: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`

```
 CREATE TABLE news` ( 
   id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   headline varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   details text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
   file varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
   created_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
   updated_at timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`
```

Comment: What kind of data do you have in database in your column with 812 characters?

Comment: What is the 256th character?

Comment: We should assume that table column is of a type that allows 812 characters? Because 255 sounds suspiciously like varchar default length.

Comment: Do you see more than 255 characters with a var_dump ?

Comment: You need to provide more context. Can you edit your question and include a representative sample of the schema in question? `SHOW CREATE TABLE` can give you this information. You should also include the `json_encode` call with sample data so we can try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: the column in which that data is saved is of type TEXT and it allows to save the 812 characters. But when i `json_encode` from the table, it doesnot show anything and when i reduce the content, it returns the json and yet i need all the content

Comment: this is what i get after i run `SHOW CREATE TABLE`  `CREATE TABLE `news` (
 `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `headline` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `details` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci`

Comment: The `255` in `file varchar(255)` is the number of characters it can hold and 812 is greater than 255. The fix is left as exercise for the reader ;-)